# Cannot navigate between pages anymore

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have a new app and I am trying to navigate to another page:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiView));
        }
```

This same code works in previous apps I've made. I don't understand why it's not working anymore.

The exception thrown is:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code   HResult=-2147467261   Message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key   Source=mscorlib   ParamName=key   StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue value)
       at MyAppName.Common.LayoutAwarePage.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) in c:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyAppName\MyAppName\Common\LayoutAwarePage.cs:line 373
       at MyAppName.MainPage.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) in c:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyAppName\MyAppName\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 804   InnerException:
```

How can I navigate to another page? (I am using the same code as described in MSDN documentation. And I've been over it many times. This has never been a problem until now.

Comment: Not a single answer? I wonder why? Am I doing something wrong here, or are you all as stumped as I am?

Comment: **Update**: The above exception points to a block of code; the OnLaunched method - within the `LayoutAwarePage.cs` page. Setting up a breakpoint revealed that, despite the exception details, `Value` was not null. Not sure what to do next, I placed that code inside a TryCatch block and my app can now navigate between pages - but the code falls through to the catch, and writes exception detail to the Output window (exception details above). So, the code still fails at some point but navigation now continues. Any suggestions on what I can do next to further investigate?

Comment: I have no idea if this will help your specific problem, but I had a similar issue stemming from a VS update. This fixed it for me: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff969be6-63c9-469c-974d-8e8649990db4/unhandled-exception-in-xaml-designer-for-winrt-application-visual-studio-2012-update-3. Specifically, running this from a command prompt as an admin: `icacls.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)" /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(CI)(F)`